Completing implementation of Google Mobile Ads SDK for Flutter project and allowing Google Analytics
I have developed an Android app which is in review in Google Play Console as of now. I have integrated ads using google_mobile_ads from the method described in its page at https://pub.dev as I use Flutter for the app development.
I realized that to be able to view Google Analytics for the Admob ads, I need to link the Admob ads with Firebase project which I did. And at the end of this linking process I got the following message:
Which says: "... make sure the following version of the SDK has been implemented in your app: Google Mobile Ads SDK 18.1.0 or later (Android) ...".
From the README page at https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads, an excerpt is below:

This repository contains the source code for the Google Mobile Ads Flutter plugin, which enables publishers to monetize Flutter apps using the Google Mobile Ads SDK.

From this I can realize that the task in the above screenshot say to ensure implementation of Google Mobile Ads SDK is done. I have implemented the SDK for Flutter.
I also made a search to how to integrate the same with Google and got this Learn how to import the Google Mobile Ads SDK to your app from this link: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/sdk . The latest Google Mobile Ads SDK 23.3.0 .
So, I have implemented the Flutter SDK for Google Mobile Ads, do I have to follow the steps stated in this link as well?
My settings.gradle does not have the following code:
dependencyResolutionManagement {
  repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}

And my build.gradle does not have the following code:
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.3.0'
}

Am I required to add these codes also even for the Flutter implementation?
On further searching, I couldn't find any information relating the two maintained versions for: Google Mobile Ads SDK and its Flutter variant google_mobile_ads package. Neither the former's release notes nor the Flutter package in pub.dev mentions the relationship.

I incorporated the changes stated in Learn how to import the Google Mobile Ads SDK to your app to my android/settings.gradle file and app level build.gradle file. Then tried to build the .apk file, and the build failed with an exception at settings.gradle page. This further makes me assume that these changes are not necessary for the Flutter version of the app. And getting Google Analytics stats concerned, I'll probably have to use Firebase codes in my app, if I really want them.
